# VB and Java desktop applications communication

Tags: java, vba, communication, desktop-application

there are two client applications running in Win XP, one of them built with VB 5 and the other wint Java 1.4. What mechanism do you recommend to exchange data between these apps ?

The chunks of data are small (max 1k), and the operation is synchronous; the VB app triggers the "request" and the Java one responds to it.

Comment: Will the two apps always run on the same machine? What kind of data will they exchange, and how much? Are there any performance requirements? Will the data go both ways or will it always only go from one to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably go for creating a simple TCP/IP server in the Java app and have the VB app connect to it and send the data when needed.

In VB6 you can use the WinSock control and I assume that this would be available for VB5 as well.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP is a protocol that's common to both.  Perhaps they can pass messages by calling web services of some kind.  You can also couple them in a database: INSERT information from one application, SELECT it in the other.  You just have to be careful about locking and isolation.